# WP7 test change orientation

Tags: windows-phone-7, testing, automation, gherkin

I use Expensify for testing. Its a great tool to work with for testing. I need to change orientation of phone in feature file. How do i do that?

Comment: I don't know Expensify but as I understand, you want to change the orientation of a page programmatically - unfortunately this can not be done.

Comment: I know this can't be done progammatically, hence the use of expensify(It connects to emulator to perform tasks). Want to know how it can be done using expensify or if it is currently not supported.

Answer (score 0):

If the framework doesn't already support it, I'd suggest extending it to manipulate the emulator to trigger rotation in the same way as is used to trigger a back key press.